# Would this cron code work?

Tags: php, cron

I just wanted someone to check this cron code for me, and let me know where to type it so that it will run on my website:

```
0 23,59 ? * MON-SUN http://mywebsite.com/phpscript.php
```

run at 11:59pm every day

```
0 23,59 ? * MON http://mywebsite.com/phpscript.php
```

run at 11:59pm on monday of every week

```
0 23,59 ? * 1 1-12 http://mywebsite.com/phpscript.php
```

run at 11:59pm on the first of every month

Would this code work? The command being run is the request to that webpage which would run that script.

Comment: Not at all. Have you tried the documentation yet?

Comment: It's a sysadmin issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: so where should I have posted it, superuser?

Comment: The SE site for sysadmin issues is Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

To get you started, the following cron entry will run every day at 11:59pm.

```
59 23 * * * wget http://mywebsite.com/phpscript.php
```

I'd strongly encourage you to [read a tutorial](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html).

Comment: haha, I only just found about about cron, be a bit gentler.

Comment: You caught me in the middle of an edit. See update.

Answer (score 0):

No, because cron doesn't know what to do with an http address - it's got to be an actual command.

You could use wget to pull from the http address - ie, instead of just having the address as the command, put `wget http://mywebsite.com/phpscript.php`

Answer (score 0):

No. You should use

```
wget http://addr
```

or better

```
php /home/.../path/to/script/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The entries need to go in the [crontab](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

You'll need to use a program like [wget](http://www.crucialp.com/resources/tutorials/server-administration/wget-how-to-use-tutorial.php), [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) or some such to actually request the page you've specified.